# Date and Time format in Cloud Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, google-cloud-functions

I am using Flutter for my mobile application. It stores date in the cloud firestore in this format.

`February 14, 2020 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+5`

But when I saved date from Cloud Functions it stores as Map

```
{
_nanoseconds: 0,
_seconds: 1582743600
}
```

I want the cloud functions to store date according to the format of Flutter.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: "It stores date in the cloud firestore in this format" - are you sure it's not just storing it as some date/time type which happens to convert to "February 14, 2020 (etc)" when you convert it to a string? Note that it would be quite unfriendly to any other application (even to yours) to store date/time data in a relatively hard-to-parse format like that. It would be like storing a number as "one thousand and one".

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It stores it as `firebase.firestore.Timestamp` ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp)).

You can import `Timestamp` using

```
import { Timestamp } from "@google-cloud/firestore";
```